# AS3 - Shader with Pixel Bender

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying out Pixel Bender but am having an error as follow.

```
ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
at flash.display::ShaderData/_setByteCode()
at flash.display::ShaderData()
at flash.display::Shader/set byteCode()
at Distorsion/onLoadComplete()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

The code that I have is

```
_loader = new URLLoader();
_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
_loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadComplete);
_loader.load(new URLRequest( "distorsion.pbj"));
```

Then this is the code that throws the error

```
private function onLoadComplete(event:Event):void {
    // this line caused the error
    shader = new Shader(event.target.data);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

The pbj file is just some sample file I copied from here http://www.kevingoldsmith.com/labs/PBSynth-v1/sinegenerator2.pbk

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: I've just compiled the and exported the kernel at it works fine(can instantiate a shader using URLoader/Embed metadata tag). Try compiling/exporting again. The error too seems to point out that there is something wrong with the shader byte code.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? What does a trace of event.target.data in onLoadComplete show?

Comment: @teepusink How come you're loading 'distorsion.pbj' if you're using the sinegenerator2.pbk kernel ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing event.target or event.currentTarget beyond the listener Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137620/accessing-event-target-or-event-currenttarget-beyond-the-listener-function)