# Accessing event.target or event.currentTarget beyond the listener Function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Originally I had two functions, the first function being `dataLoaded` which had an eventListener in it that spawned a new function called `itemClicked`. But if I wanted to add a `delayedFunction` and have `itemClicked` as an intermittent stage between `dataLoaded` and `delayedFunction`, how can I access the `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` of the original listener when I come to reference it in my `delayedFunction`?

```
private function dataLoaded(event:Event):void {
    //items properties call - add other calls to master properties later on
    items = data.item;
    // parsing of each ingredient
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
        // instantiation of mcItem (the stage for each item)
        _item = new Item();
        // sets //over// layer to invisible / transparent
        _item.item_btn_over.alpha = 0;
        // creates the var itemTextField
        _itemTextField = new TextField();
        _itemTextField.text = items[i].toString();
        // adds textfield to displaylist
        _item.addChild(_itemTextField);
        //adds items to container displaylist
        _container.addChild(_item);
    }
    _item.parent.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClicked );
}

function itemClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
    if (event.target is Item) {
        var item:Item = Item(event.target);
        TweenLite.to(item.btn_delete, 1,{rotation:180});
        setTimeout(delayedFunction,5000);
        item.parent.removeChild(item);
        parseXML(data);
    }
}

function delayedFunction():void {
    var item:Item = Item(event.target);
    item.parent.removeChild(item);
}
```

(I've mocked up the functions above, so I may be missing some closing parenthesis, but this doesn't matter in relation to my question)

This question has been on my mind for days and I can't think of a way of making the `event.target` of the parent `_item` accessible to functions other than the listening function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass arguments to your `setTimeout` call like this:

```
setTimeout(delayedFunction, 5000, event.currentTarget);
```

Then get the argument from the `arguments` array from your `delayedFunction` method:

```
function delayedFunction():void {
    var item:Item = arguments[0] as Item;
    item.parent.removeChild(item);
}
```

Have a look at the [setTimeout docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout%28%29) if you need information.

Comment: Do I need to declare the arguments array or is `arguments` a built-in keyword for passing arguments?

Comment: No you do not need to declare the `arguments` array. It is made for every function. Have a look as the docs for arguments (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/arguments.html])